# What are the physical security features that prevent the cryptographic data on a SIM card being read?

Tags: physical, physical-access, simcard

In his excellent answer to "[How does a SIM card prevent cloning?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/64294/how-does-a-sim-card-prevent-cloning)", user Lie Ryan explains that SIM cards have their critical data stored in "tamper proof housing", protected by "physical security measures [designed] to make reading the key from the card very difficult".

**What are these "physical security measures", and how do they work?**

Has anyone ever successfully read the security key directly from the physical memory of a modern SIM card?

Answer (score 1):

SIM cards are just smart cards, so apart from pointing to the generic definition of [Tamper Resistant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tamper_resistant#Chips), I'm not sure much can be said in general.

Looking up the manufacturer specs may provide additional info. For example, Gemalto (a specialist in hardware crypto chips) manufacturers a large number of the world's SIM cards. [Their marketing page](http://www.gemalto.com/companyinfo/digital-security/techno/sim) says this:

> With a microprocessor base, SIM cards are similar to a mini-computer with its own operating system, storage and built-in security features. When configured with up-to-date cryptography, as recommended by NIST, BSI, ANSSI, etc., SIM cards provide a level of security that is state-of-the-art.

That's all kinda vacuous and fluffy, bet it's reasonable to assume that SIM chips will contain similar security technologies to Gemalto's [FIPS 140-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIPS_140-2#Security_levels) certified products.

---

This excellent answer by @ThomasPornin is also relevant:

https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31051/61443

Comment: Hi @Mike Ounsworth, thanks for your answer. You provide a link to material that describes some of the tamper resistance mechanisms, but It would be great if you could describe some of them directly.

Comment: @JamieVicary I work a lot with FIPS 140-2 on the software side, which is why I know that it's a relevant reference, but unfortunately I don't enough about hardware to describe the security features other than copying wikipedia (which makes this a fairly weak answer, I know).